# Should the aperture ring of a Canonet GIII QL17 have detent stops all the way round?

Tags: repair, rangefinder

I'm repairing one, and don't currently have another to compare it with.

The aperture ring has detent stops on the *A*/*28*/*20*/*14* positions, but through the the f-stops section it rotates continuously, without stops.

Is this normal, or should it have distinct stops all the way round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to check with another example. The aperture ring **doesn't** have stops all the way round.